# Angular route is not working on single click but clicking again is working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, routes, ngroute

I have a data service which will process all my data related operations and all these operations are asynchronous.

Once I click on ERASE button there is one function which erase all data and return an object that contains operation status (Success: true /false).

Based on this value (TRUE) I need to route to another view (Say Data Successfully erased page).

But when I click on button for the first time routing is not happening (But erase function is giving the correct value (true).
However if I click again the same button , the route is happening.

Here how I am using my **removeDatabase()** ( part of dataService ) function.

```js
    self.removeDatabase = function () {
        //$location.path("/setup");
        dataService.resetDatabase().done(function (msgs) {
            if(msgs['Operation_success']){
                console.log("Operation is Success ? :"+msgs['Operation_success']);
                $location.path("/setup");
                //self.loadSetup();
            }
        });
    },
```

Here is the function inside the service.

```js
appdata.resetDatabase = function () {
        appdata.msgs = {};
        var deferred = jQuery.Deferred();
        appdata.db = window.openDatabase("finbud_db", "1.0", "FinBud", 20);

        var d1 = jQuery.Deferred();
        appdata.db.transaction(function (tx) {
            tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS BASE_TABLE');
        }, function () {
            appdata.msgs['BASE_TABLE'] = "Could not Delete";
            appdata.msgs['Operation_success'] = false;
            d1.resolve();
        }, function () {
            appdata.msgs['BASE_TABLE'] = "Deleted";
            appdata.msgs['Operation_success'] = true;
            d1.resolve();
        });

        var d2 = jQuery.Deferred();
        appdata.db.transaction(function (tx) {
            tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS CATEGORY_TABLE');
        }, function () {
            appdata.msgs['CATEGORY_TABLE'] = "Could not Delete";
            appdata.msgs['Operation_success'] = false;
            d2.resolve();
        }, function () {
            appdata.msgs['CATEGORY_TABLE'] = "Deleted";
            appdata.msgs['Operation_success'] = true;
            d2.resolve();
        });

        var d3 = jQuery.Deferred();
        appdata.db.transaction(function (tx) {
            tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ACCOUNTS_TABLE');
        }, function () {
            appdata.msgs['ACCOUNTS_TABLE'] = "Could not Delete";
            appdata.msgs['Operation_success'] = false;
            d3.resolve();
        }, function () {
            appdata.msgs['ACCOUNTS_TABLE'] = "Deleted";
            appdata.msgs['Operation_success'] = true;
            d3.resolve();
        });

        var d4 = jQuery.Deferred();
        appdata.db.transaction(function (tx) {
            tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TRANSACTIONS_TABLE');
        }, function () {
            appdata.msgs['TRANSACTIONS_TABLE'] = "Could not Delete";
            appdata.msgs['Operation_success'] = false;
            d4.resolve();
        }, function () {
            appdata.msgs['TRANSACTIONS_TABLE'] = "Deleted";
            appdata.msgs['Operation_success'] = true;
            d4.resolve();
        });

        jQuery.when(d1, d2, d3, d4).done(function () {
            deferred.resolve(appdata.msgs);
        });
        return deferred.promise();

    };
```

Finally HTML is :

```html
    <md-button  ng-click="appCtrl.removeDatabase();">
        <i class="mdi mdi-reload"></i> Reset App 
    </md-button>
```

Any help appreciated.
ThankYou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call `$scope.$digest()` to notify angular that something has changed. I suggest using angular built in `$q` promise library instead of jquery promises:

```
var d1 = $q.defer();
...
d1.resolve();
...
return $q.all([d1, d2, d3, d4]).then(function () {
    return appdata.msgs;
});
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for answer. It Solved my problem.  But in Success function I am not getting the data which is promised.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. If I console "dataService.resetDatabase()" , I am getting promise object. ( Of course it has $$state.value ). But I am trying "dataService.resetDatabase().then(function(data){});"  way. In this case I am still getting empty. What I am missing ?

Comment: @ManiKumarAkasapu debug `appdata.msgs` in console

Comment: It is available in each function. But not at inside the return().then()

Comment: Thank you So much karaxuna. The above issue is some thing not related to this question. I figured out solution. Thanks Again.

Comment: I am posted the solution assuming that will help somebody.

Answer (score 1):

The answer provided by karaxuna is right. This is extension for the answer.

If I do like below, This will return all 4 promises in one. The required data is **appdata.msgs** which is inside each of the promise (inside d.$$state).

```js
var d1 = $q.defer();
...
d1.resolve();
...
return $q.all([d1, d2, d3, d4]).then(function () {
    return appdata.msgs;
});
```

By default all functions will return the deferred object. But I want to explicitly return the **appdata.msgs**. So Now I need 4 functions that will return data instead of deferred.

To achieve this I am resolving the promise with **appdata.msgs** (also returning the same at the end) at each of the four functions.

Now **all()** function will return **appdata.msgs** after all these functions are resolved ( remember I resolved with **appdata.msgs**).

Code is below:

```js
 function d1() {
   
   var d1 = $q.defer();
   
   ......
   //some where
   d1.resolve(msgs);
   .......
   
   return d1.promise;
}

................

 function dN() {
   
   var dN = $q.defer();
   
   ......
   //some where
   dN.resolve(msgs);
   .......
   
   return dN.promise;
}

return $q.all([d1(), d2(),  ....., dN()]).then(
  
         function () {
  
            return msgs;
  
         },
               
         function(){
  
            msgs['Operation_success'] = false;
            return msgs;
  
         });
```

Correct me if my understanding is wrong.
Thankyou.